# Save HTML file including values of input tags using PHP

Tags: php, html, file, save, using

How can I save all of the values of input tags (text, radio, textarea, etc.) into an HTML file? When a user sets the value of the input tags and clicks the button to save, the code will save the current webpage as an HTML file and include the value of the input tags. I tried to use following code, but it didn't work. I only get an HTML file with empty input tags.

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#full_name').change(function(){
     $('#full_name').attr('value',$(this).val());
});
$('#comment').change(function(){
      $('#comment').html($(this).val());
});

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="handle_form.php" method="post">
<input name="full_name" id="name"/>
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
file_put_contents('test.html',$content);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is running on the server-side before the user entered any input. In order to save the data the user entered, you should either `submit` it (using an HTML `form`) to your server, or use `AJAX` to update your server.

Comment: Thank a lot!.But in my application,user will append a lot of textarea tags  and i won't know how many textarea tags appended to save data.My application is an English Test for student.In there,teachers will create so many questions.In each question,teachers can import a lot of textarea tags if they want.So i want to save current page into a html file(such as examID.html) include value of those textarea tags.Then,students will do the test througt an examID and application will inport examID.html into the the page.How can i do that.How can i use value which submitted,how to use AJAX,thank!

Comment: There are many AJAX tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp and http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ are just two examples. Still, I'm not sure that using AJAX here will be simpler than submitting a form. Your call ;)